# Angular 2 split form to multiple views

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, model-view-controller, angular

I'm making an quiz application, where Angular retrieves an array of categories form server, each category consisting of multiple questions.

I use following high level structure for the views:

```
<quiz>
 <form>
   <category/>
   <formNavigation/>
 </form>
</quiz>
```

Where CategoryComponent's model is bound to the active category object of quiz, which is changed by the buttons in formNavigation view.

Because input fields are added to form inside a view, previous inputs are discarded when navigating to next category, which is not desirable. How I preserve the inputs of previous view in the form, when going to the next category, i.e. splitting form to multiple navigable views?

Comment: You can save your old state in session somewhere before discarding it.Then afterwards retrieve values in next splitted form.